# Getting id for Custom Admin Actions

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I want to get the id of a query set that is selected in the admin panel and want this custom action to redirect me to the url having the id in it. However I am not able to do so.

**admin.py:**

```
@admin.register(models.PurchaseItem)
class PurchaseItemAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = (
        'id',
        'product', 'supplier', 'quantity')


    @admin.action(description='View Invoice')
    def get_context_data(self, request, query_set):
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/purchases/10/generatePDF')


    actions = [get_context_data]
```

I want to be able to have any id instead of hardcoding '10' in the url to that when I select a query, I can use the custom command to redirect to its pdf page.

Answer (score 1):

Just pass id thorw self by super or anyway and just call

```
'/purchases/%s/generatePDF' % self.id
```

some thing like this

Comment: can you explain the full code

Comment: it does not work

Comment: I would love if you wrote the full code